# Good practice to develop in MVC and repository iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, code-reuse

I'm starting an app in iOS which will use a SQLite database.

I would like to reuse the code of this app for others in future.

I would like to make first a view associate to a ViewModel.

I will use a repository for my data. First, it will be generate, and after, data from SQLite database.

Then, when I'll use the database, just change some stuff in my ViewModel and all will work good...

I don't know if you see what I mean...

Do you know some good practices to do this? Tutorials, explanation, or anything else interesting?

**EDIT:**

I would like to follow this way:

- Repository can be database data or random generated data for testing before I have the database...
- ViewModel is the "model of myt view" which set all objects of my view with the data fetched in my Repository...

I understand the idea, but I don't know how to proceed to do this and I found nothing about the method... Maybe it's not a good way ?

If you have any suggestion, please let me know ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object class for the interaction with the sqlite, Preferred will be a singleton class which could also be used as intermediary storing class.

Comment: Thank you! But, if I generate some data to test my views with my viewModel, and after use data from sqlite, how can I override generated data by sqlite data ? I don't know how to proceed :/

Comment: You have to update sqlite , as we do in SQL operations. Your best bet will be to use coredate , its an apple's framework which provide  MVC

Comment: I know CoreData framework. I used it for an application. But here, it's not the question how to update or to use data from SQLite. It's how can I, after test views with my own data (some loops to set my views), override these data with SQLite data without change anything in my modelView. Is it possible ? Thank you ;)